# SQL - Detecting a duplicate in a column only if they share a value in another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this MYSQL table:

```
Name    |  Age | X
--------------------
Andrew  |   7  |
Andrew  |   7  |
Andrew  |  10  |  
John    |   9  |
John    |  11  | 
John    |  11  |
```

And I would like to assign a value to those names that share age, like this:

```
Name    |  Age | X
--------------------
Andrew  |   7  | x
Andrew  |   7  | x
Andrew  |  10  |  
John    |   9  |
John    |  11  | x
John    |  11  | x
```

Have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Which `DBMS` ?....

Comment: use `having` in query

Answer (score 2):

If your database supports `window` functions then

```
Select Name,Age,
       case when count(Age)over(partition by Name, Age) > 1 then 'x' else '' end as X
FROM yourtable
```

If no(`Mysql`), then

```
Select Name,Age,
       case when (select count(Age) from yourtable b where a.Name = b.Name and a.Age = b.Age) > 1 then 'x' else '' end as X
FROM yourtable a
```

Comment: It looks like OP want a partition by name and age. Apart from that your queries are fine. But why `count(1)`? You'd use `count(<expression>)` to count non-null values. `count(1)` means: "evaluate 1 for every row and count it in case it is not null". You get the same result as if you were simply counting rows (`count(*)`), so why the extra work?

Comment: Haha, now you count `Age`. Do you expect it to be null sometimes? I still think you only want to count rows, which is `count(*)`.

Comment: @Prdp,+1 Answer is very simple and nice way.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - Yes It can be `null` we don't know right.. Though it will get rejected in where clause

Answer (score 1):

As MySQL doesn't support window functions, you must read the table twice. Here is one way to do this:

```
select name, age, dups.x
from persons p
left join
(
  select name, age, 'x' as x
  from persons
  group by name, age
  having count(*) > 1
) dups using (name, age)
order by name, age;
```

Answer (score 0):

--detecting duplicate column with all columns

```
    with cte as
    (select name, age ,x , row_number () over (partition by name,age,x order by 
   name) RowNum from Table 
    ) select name,age,x from cte where rownum > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For sure this one will work .Just try it ...:). Easy and sensible!

```
   Select Name,Age,count(*)   
   INTO #TempTable 
   FROM yourtable 
   group by   Name,Age
   having count(*) >1


update a 
set a.X= "X"
from yourtable a 
      join #TempTable b on  a.Name=b.Name and a.Age =b.Age

drop table #TempTable
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't support the WITH clause :(

Comment: how?! are u sure ? if you are in the middle of code you must start with ; .otherwise you should seprate it by , . anyway I updated it for you and use temp table.

Comment: just don't forget to drop all temp table at the end ,always

Comment: it doesn't.. :S